# need to change colour of a selected word in a paragraph in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Exactly like the attached [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLpXG.png) i need to select a word from the paragraph and highlight the particular word.

We tried using rich text but id doesn’t meet our requirement(we need to select a word and highlight it) so we need a alternate way to achieve this using flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RichText. Text widget uses it internally. You can provide list of TextSpan with different styles.

Comment: yes we are proceeding with richText widget only thanks for the confimration